# Delete all azure event grid subscriptions using Azure CLI

Tags: azure-cli, azure-eventgrid

I am using event grid for my web api. The domain name of my api have changed and now I need to update all event grid subscriptions. It so happends that I have Azure CLI command to create each subscription, so the easiest way would be to delete all of them and create new ones. I have checked the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/eventgrid/event-subscription?view=azure-cli-latest#az-eventgrid-event-subscription-delete) but `az eventgrid event-subscription delete` command requires `--name` parameter which means that I need to execute this manually for each subscriptions. While this is not a huge problem it would require to maintain second command list for deleting. It would be much faster if I could simply say `--all` or something similar.

Maybe there is a solution to delete all event grid subscriptions without too much of o hassle?

My ideas so far:

- Drop entire event grid topic and create new one (*seems a bit excessive*)
- Apply some bash magic with `az eventgrid event-subscription list`

Comment: Is your source interest is a domain topic? If yes, see my comment to the @JimXu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my test, we can use the following command to delete a list of subscriptions that are associated with Azure event gird topic in [Azure Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview).

```
results=$(az eventgrid event-subscription list --source-resource-id /subscriptions/{SubID}/resourceGroups/{RG}/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/domains/domain1/topics/topic1 --query "[].{Name:name}")


for row in $(echo "$results" | jq -r '.[]|"\(.Name)"')
do
  az eventgrid event-subscription delete --name $row --source-resource-id  /subscriptions/{SubID}/resourceGroups/{RG}/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/domains/domain1/topics/topic1
done
```

[image]

Comment: In the case, where the *source-resource-id* is a **domain topic**, we don't need to walk through the list of the subscriptions and individually delete one by one. Instead of this loop we can delete a *domain topic* (the source of interest). Note, that the last deleted subscription in the loop process will delete also a domain topic, anyway. This is a unique case in the AEG eventing model, where the domain topic can be created by the consumer side (by subscription).